# Indexing SQLAlchemy models on ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy signals to keep an elasticsearch index updated reflecting certain models on my DB.

The problem I'm having is that to build the ES documents I access some of the models' relationships, and that means that there's several points at the signals cycle the relationships cannot be accessed. I was creating the ES Document from the Model instance in the listeners for `after_(insert|udpate|delete)`, but those are issued while the connection is in `flushing` state, and it seems like relationships return `None` at that point, so the ES document cannot be built.

I changed it so I just saved queue of the commands to be emitted, keeping a reference to the model instead, and the plan was to issue them on commit, but the `before_commit` signal is issued *before* flushing, and when `after_commit` is issued the DB cannot be accessed anymore, so again relationships are inaccessible.

It seems to me like the right moment to create the Documents and save them is in the `after_flush_postexec` signal, but I have a feeling that between that and when the `commit` is actually issued there might be a rollback, and then the ES index would not reflect the DB anymore.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.

Here's the code I'm working with right now. `ChargeIndexer.upsert` takes a SQLAlchemy ORM model, and uses the elasticsearch api to insert/update a document built from it and `.delete` does the same, except of course it deletes it, and only depends on the model's `id`.

```
class ChargeListener(object):

    ops = []

    @event.listens_for(Charge, 'after_delete', propagate=True)
    def after_delete(mapper, connection, target):
        ChargeListener.add_delete(target)

    @event.listens_for(Charge, 'after_insert', propagate=True)
    def after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
        ChargeListener.add_insert(target)

    @event.listens_for(Charge, 'after_update', propagate=True)
    def after_update(mapper, connection, target):
        ChargeListener.add_insert(target)

    @classmethod
    def execute_ops(cls):
        charges_indexer = ChargesIndexer()
        for op, charge in ChargeListener.ops:
            if op == 'insert':
                charges_indexer.upsert(charge)
            elif op == 'delete':
                charges_indexer.delete(charge)

        ChargeListener.reset()

    @event.listens_for(sess, 'after_flush_postexec')
    def after_flush_postexec(session, flush_context):
        ChargeListener.execute_ops()

    @event.listens_for(sess, 'after_soft_rollback')
    def after_soft_rollback(session, previous_transaction):
        ChargeListener.reset()

    @classmethod
    def add_insert(cls, charge):
        cls.ops.append(('insert', charge))

    @classmethod
    def add_delete(cls, charge):
        cls.ops.append(('delete', charge))

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        cls.ops = []
```